# What's the best way to do a jQuery autocomplete tag that draws data from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery-ui, gql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t76TR/) that is basically from jqueryui. Yes, it is raw and the example uses JSON to handle the autocompleting process. My back end developers are using python on GAE and they usually just draw data out from the gql direct and dump it into the webpage. i need this function to create tags just like stackoverflow. What is the best practice in my situation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whiff includes support for both GAE, jqueryUI, and AJAX that works really well for me.  Have a look at http://whiffdoc.appspot.com -- particularly the tutorials.